# Installing new gnome plugins on Ubuntu 22.04 automatically turned off

Tags: gnome

I started having trouble installing gnome plugins since my newly installation of Ubuntu 22.04. I didn't experience this from prior Ubuntu versions. After installing the plugin "Switcher" see [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/973/switcher/)

It was successfully installed but after closing the gnome plugin homepage ( Chrome ) it goes automatically turned off. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, installing the right version for my Gnome version but still it gets automatically turned off

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVKhC.png)

Hope anyone can help me. I love ubuntu and the switcher plugin has always been part of my workflow

Answer (score 1):

Update: Fixed the issue. I just installed the gnome extension manager by running this command on terminal

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

The Gnome extensions can be switched on after typing "extensions" in the activities search box.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't install the Gnome Tweaks or any app that manages the gnome extensions. I just installed the gnome-chrome-extensions via terminal and I just open the chrome browser and go to the gnome extensions to install the extensions. 

But every time i switch it on it automatically goes back to off which is frustrating